# How can I override the "part of app-pipeline" buildname?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

We are migrating a set of jobs (concerning the same codebase) to a pipeline. The main reason for the split into multiple jobs was the achieved parallelism and finegrained return-values. The pipeline/Jenkinsfile-approach seems to be a good fit. Some plugins are still missing but all in all we're on a good track.

One of the things that we are missing, is the good naming we had before. Before, each build would get a name like `$jobname $buildnumber ($branch)`, which gave us `app-spec #42 (new-feature)`. This lead to nice visibility in the jenkins "executor status"-sidebar.

With the pipeline, we only get `part of app-pipeline #23`, which forces us to look into the build and determine what is running at any given moment in time.

Is there a way to override the name that is shown in the sidebar?

**UPDATE**

I mostly want the answer to "what part of the parallelized pipeline is running in that executor".

Comment: any solutions yet?

Comment: sadly no. currently, our migration of the separate jobs to one pipeline is simply on hold because of this (and other non-technical aspects).

Comment: Recent Jenkins Pipeline plugins versions shows the current stage name in the sidebar. Did you enclose your stages in `stage("stage name") {}` blocks? Same goes for parallel blocks, just give them meaningful names.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a `stage('name'){}` block in each parallel entry. The name of the stage will appear in the executor status. So name your stages whatever you want to see in the status.

Note, the `"part of ..."` label will still show in the build queue, but executor status will show correctly.

```
parallel (
    'newOne': { stage('new-feature'){ //all the things } },
    'second': { stage('second branch'){ //all the things } },
    'third': { stage('third branch'){ //all the things } },
)
```

The executor will show

```
jobname #nnn (new-feature) 
jobname #nnn (second branch)
jobname #nnn (third branch)
```

**EDIT:** I ran a test pipeline that is simulating a multiconfig job with 3 axes: OS, JDK Fruit. Each branch of the config combinations runs in parallel and has a named branch. The executor status indicates each combination running:

[image]

Comment: Is it `stage` or `branch`? I already use `stage('name')` which doesn't end up changing anything on the executor status. When I tried branch, I got `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'branch' found among steps `.

Comment: Oops. Stage. Confusing terms. What version of Jenkins are you using? I tested on a test instance of 2.83 and it worked great.

Comment: I just added a screenshot of my test.

Comment: Looks better, I'm really looking for a way to change the "multi-configPipeline" part from a build script, that'd be ideal. I'm running Jenkins v2.32.1 with pipeline plugin v2.4

Comment: Hmmm... Yeah, changing the display to not display the name of the job itself in the executor would probably require a plugin of some kind. If you could change the name of the job temporarily (i.e. through groovy), it would probably show the same change on every executor at the same time.

Comment: For me, this works fine. I've changed my setup slightly, so this is what I use now. @nickb maybe open a new question if this does not help you (sorry).

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
currentBuild.displayName = "My friendly name"
```

Comment: I've tried this and it gives me "part of app-pipeline  #23 (new-feature)". While this adds some information, I still don't know if it's running specs, static analysis or integration tests. We also parallelize a lot to spread the build-time over as many executors as possible.

Comment: Descriptor setter plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin but for me this updates the executor post completion.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
currentBuild.displayName="${JOB_NAME} ${BUILD_NUMBER} (${BRANCH})"
```

If it a declarative pipeline, you need to wrap it with a script{}:

```
script
{
    currentBuild.displayName="${JOB_NAME} ${BUILD_NUMBER} (${BRANCH})"
}
```

Comment: This changes the build name, not the job name. The job name is where the indicated text is coming from. Plus, making this change in the parallel stages over and over just makes the problem worse. Now instead of a build number in the executor status, you will see whatever name was set at the time you loaded the UI, but that same build name will show for all executors.

Comment: Changing the job name will cause change of folder name in the 'build' and 'workdpace' folders. This cannot and should not be done during the build time!

Comment: Agreed. You can't change the job name. You could potentially build a plugin that displays something other than the job name in the executor. But changing the build displayName does not solve this problem, and could make it more confusing.

Comment: I don't see why adding the job name and the branch name to the build number - that is already there - more confusing

Comment: Because in the original post, they are operating on multiple branches in parallel. The name of the build in the executor will only show whatever it was set to when the web UI loaded. And it will show it for ALL the currently running threads. So you may be running branch A, B, C, and D at the same time, but if C was the last one to set the display name before you loaded the web screen that shows the executor status, ALL of the executor nodes will show C, even though they are running A, B, and C.

Comment: Yes. Do you want a screenshot? The name displayed in the executor shows the current build name. It doesn't show the build name as it was when that executor started running.

Comment: Each time the screen refreshes, every executor changes the build name as each parallel step changes the displayName. This is the same matrix job simulator I used in my answer. The build name is the same on each one. In the parens, it shows the real "thread" it is running. https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNCng.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLbvX.jpg

Comment: WOW. Looks like a big Jenkins-internal bug.

Comment: Ha. Ok, open an issue on it and see where it goes. That isn't a bug.

Comment: As you describes it - looks like it shows the wrong branch for an executor. Am I wrong?

Comment: It shows it wrong where it is showing the currentBuild.displayName. But that is because it just shows what the build is called at the time you see it, not what it was set to when the 'thread' started executing. This is working exactly as it should work. The build's display name is just the name of the build that is displayed on screen when you view it.